# Opencart - how to find which file add a menu on admin header

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to add a custom menu on my admin dashboard as a dropdown link that's based on Opencart. I've changed my header.tpl and related files and it's ok . The problem is here that when it shows the menu , it adds some other links that i don't want to be there :(
I've checked vqmode file and it doesn't have anything for that . i don't know what is wrong with me that i can't find the file that add those menus ?

[Link To Screenshot](http://www.uploadax.com/images/28524559648309100843.png)

this is what i have in header.tpl file for that menu :

```
<li id="help"><a class="top" onclick="window.open('xxxx');"><?php echo $text_help; ?>
    <ul id="training">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $training_video_link; ?>"><?php echo $text_training_video; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</a>

</li>
```

and this is what i have after rendering :

```
<li id="help" class="sfHover"><a class="top" onclick="window.open('xxx/support/');">Help        </a><ul id="training" style="display: block; visibility: visible;"><a class="top" onclick="window.open('xxx/support/');">
        </a><li><a class="top" onclick="window.open('xxx/support/');"></a><a href="xxx/admin/index.php?route=mall_module/training/help&amp;token=c20ad4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710">Trainig Videos</a></li>
    </ul>


</li>
```

Comment: This is an HTML & CSS issue not PHP

Comment: There is no html & css there that doing this !

Comment: The thing is the admin theme is using some JS navigation menu, and all this classes, styles, links are generated via this navigation JS thing... From my point of view, if the navigation is working fine, You should not lose time with this one... But since You have this empty space I guess in Your base HTML markup something is causing the unnecessary links to appear. Simply check how is the menu in header done (the HTML markup) and write Your new item the same way (**but probably won't work on default admin theme then**)...

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you've added it seems like you're using an admin theme installed via vqmod file. The links that appear in the 'Help' menu are default opencart links. So you need to remove those links in header.tpl or from the admin theme xml file.

Steps to try:

1. Rename the vqmod/xml folder and check. If the issue doesn't exist, then searched in xml files.
2. (step 1 failed to help) Search again in admin\view\template\common\header.tpl to see whether there's anything under `<li id="help"><a class="top"><?php echo $text_help; ?></a>`.
3. (step 1 & 2 failed to help) Rename 'admin\view\template\common\header.tpl' to confirm that you were working on the correct template file.

Comment: as you can see , there are 3 same link after rendering while it's not exist in tpl file .i've checked the xml file on /vqmode on root folder . i guess there is a vqmod for admin that's not in /vqmod folder . any idea ?

Comment: please read my question better , i've changed the header.tpl so i could find the correct header.tpl file.as you can see there is nothing under that menu html so 2th step isn't answer.i've checked the vqmod too and that's not answer as i mentioned at top.

Comment: That's why I've added step 3 also. Check whether header.tpl is your template file. Even though header.tpl is the default admin header template file, sometimes you (or your co-developer) or your theme may be using another template file for the header controller. I don't know any other standard method than writing code in template file or vqmod xml file for the admin menu. Please make sure that you've tried all the 3 steps I mentioned. Also post the solution when you fix this issue.
Have a nice day :) !

Comment: oops, i found the problem . it was missing end-tag for a tag for top menu. just take a look at top codes , you may understand where i was wrong :) . tnx for your help anyway